# If you toss a handful of confetti onto a comb, why does some of it stick and some of it fly away?

Tags: electricity, induction

My guess is some paper pieces happen to be charged with the opposite charge compared to the comb, so they are attracted, but once they touch the comb, their charge is neutralized. But the comb is bigger and has a bigger charge, so it is still charged. Now paper is an insulator and those neutral confetti which is sticked to it will remain sticked because of induction. Am I right?

I've seen this in a [Walter Lewin's lesson](http://video.mit.edu/watch/the-wonders-of-electricity-and-magnetism-9964/) (24:21), he left the question as a challenge. In the same lessos, he also rubbed some ballons and stuck them to the blackboard, even to people... all ballons remained stuck, except for one, which was too heavy. I guess that could also be explained by induction, which presupposes both blackboard is not a good conductor and the same goes for (dry) human hairs and clothes.

Comment: yes i would say your answer is correct, you can answer your own question